# How do I align two divs on the left and right vertically?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a problem trying to align my dropdown list vertically with my textarea on the left somehow. I do not know why it is clashing together.

EDIT:Thanks for the help, I have made changes to achieve it.

JSP:

```css
.ExeDropdown{
   float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
}
div.txt1{
    float: left;
    margin-left:50px;
}
div.txt2{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 120px;
}
.txt3{
   float:right;
   margin-right: 120px;
}
#subBtn{
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left:47%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ExeDropdown">
    Select an exercise: 
    <select name="ProgExe">
      <option value="exe1">Exercise 1</option>
      <option value="exe2">Exercise 2</option>
    </select>
</div>    
<div class="txt1" >
    <p>Write your source code here:</p>
    <textarea id="myTextArea" rows="5" cols="40" name="txtInput" >
    </textarea>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vok8d.jpg

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: i would like my div.exedropdown to be above my div.txt1 aligned on the left

Comment: Tim, did it work?

Comment: it didnt unfortunately , i was expecting the div.exedrop & div.txt1 to be aligned on left vertically like how two right divs are aligned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

HTML:

```
<div class="ExeDropdown">
Select an exercise: 
<select name="ProgExe">
  <option value="exe1">Exercise 1</option>
  <option value="exe2">Exercise 2</option>
</select>
</div>    
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="txt1" >
<p>Write your source code here:</p>
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows="5" cols="40" name="txtInput" >
</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `float:left;` on both of the elements you mentioned (.ExeDropdown, div.txt1).

it should work then

Answer (score -1):

Add a (line-) break before it:

```
Select an exercise: 
<br /> <!-- here -->
<select name="ProgExe">
```